# Syntax error in EXEC(@sql) in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I'm coding a sp to use in an asp.net page which displays a gridview (with multiple pages) and checkboxes for the select query. However it gives me syntax error on the `EXEC(@sql)`, can't I call it within the if after using the `WITH...AS` ?

```
SET @sql=@sql +' ' +' FROM DATASET WHERE (RowId BETWEEN (@page - 1) * @pageSize AND (@page) * @pageSize)
    OR (@page IS NULL)'


if @filter='pt'
    BEGIN
    WITH DataSet AS
    (
        SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
            row_number() over(order by date desc) as 'RowId'
            , convert(varchar(10), date 105) AS 'date'
            , product1
            , product2
            , product3
            , product4
            , Y
            , N
            FROM (select date
        , count(case when product='product1' then 1 else null end) as 'product1'
        , count(case when product='product2' then 1 else null end) as 'product1'
        , count(case when product='product3' then 1 else null end) as 'product1'
        , count(case when onsale='Y' then 1 else null end) as 'Y'
        , count(case when onsale='N' then 1 else null end) as 'N'
        from dbo.vwSales
        group by date) as o
        WHERE
            (date BETWEEN @from AND @to)    
    )
    EXEC (@sql)
    END
```

Comment: your @sql variable has to start with SELECT, also please provide the description of the error

Comment: Sorry, it has started but i just didnt copy it because it is a result of a long if's to check the ticked checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have the whole SQL in the variable for the Exec -command, starting with the "with ...".

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is something we're not seeing here, there is no reason to execute dynamic SQL here. Writing dynamic SQL and executing it with EXEC is generally an anti-pattern, as it opens you up to the possibility of writing some inefficient code with security problems.

Can you just run...

```
WITH DataSet AS
    (
        SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
            row_number() over(order by date desc) as 'RowId'
            , convert(varchar(10), date 105) AS 'date'
            , product1
            , product2
            , product3
            , product4
            , Y
            , N
            FROM (select date
        , count(case when product='product1' then 1 else null end) as 'product1'
        , count(case when product='product2' then 1 else null end) as 'product1'
        , count(case when product='product3' then 1 else null end) as 'product1'
        , count(case when onsale='Y' then 1 else null end) as 'Y'
        , count(case when onsale='N' then 1 else null end) as 'N'
        from dbo.vwSales
        group by date) as o
        WHERE
            (date BETWEEN @from AND @to)    
    )
FROM DATASET WHERE (RowId BETWEEN (@page - 1) * @pageSize AND (@page) * @pageSize)
    OR (@page IS NULL)
```

Also note that the "TOP 100 PERCENT" is unnecessary.

Comment: My asp.net page has a checkbox list with each one of the products and if it was on sale or not, so i have to write the dynamic SQL in which I define the columns to select from that dataset (accordingly to the ticked checkboxes, whose value i pass to SQL as BIT), or can i do this differently?

Comment: OK, that does make it challenging. Personally, I prefer to build that kind of dynamic SQL from the code side through an ORM tool, rather than create a stored procedure with EXEC. That gives you something that is more manageable in terms of test automation.